# Json file not found after publishing production code of Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, angular6

I am fetching data from local JSON file placed in assets folder.

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getLanguages(){
    return this.http.get("./assets/data.json").toPromise();
  }
}
```

I am getting data perfectly in development enviroment. But, when I build project using `ng build --prod` and publish to GoDaddy. I am getting following error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): e:
>   {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not
>   Found","url":"http://example.com/assets/data.json","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http
>   failure response for
>   http://example.com/assets/data.json: 404 Not
>   Found","error":"\r\nhttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n\r\n\r\n404 - File or directory not
>   found.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
>
> ## Server Error
>
> \r\n\r\n
>   \r\n
>
> ### 404 - File or
>   directory not found.
>
> \r\n
>
> #### The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.
>
> \r\n
>   \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

I've placed the JSON file correctly into assets folder in GoDaddy as well. but issue is with published version only.
[image]

Comment: Are there assets in the `css` and `images` folder that are returned without error?

Comment: @TheHeadRush - Yes, I am getting CSS, Images and js without any error. issue is just with json file

Comment: It's apparently a hosting issue. Seems GoDaddy doesn't set a MIME type for `.json` (i mean, why would you want that anyway?). For more info: https://www.godaddy.com/community/Plesk-Hosting/GET-json-404-Not-Found/m-p/40297/thread-id/4759

Comment: Please provider your `angular.json`

Comment: Yes, I've to add Mime Type in Web server setting of GoDaddy